# Problems centering elements

Tags: html, css

I'm coding my menus, this time using CSS for the animations and js to change the classes from showing, to hidden and semi hidden. (I haven't started on the js yet)

Some problems I'm not figuring how to fix (getting really stressed).

- Why the top margin isn't 0?
- Why is there some padding/margin/wtv on the left and top side between the divs?
- How can I center the links vertically? (I think I need to keep using 100% and position fixed and overflow hidden because I need to move the divs out of the screen)

```css
html,
body {
  background: #E6E6E6;
}
.menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all ease .65s;
  -moz-transition: all ease .65s;
  -ms-transition: all ease .65s;
  -o-transition: all ease .65s;
  transition: all ease .65s;
}
.left {
  right: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.left.bar {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: -60px;
}
.left.hidden {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.menu > .links {
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.menu li {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 1s;
  -ms-transition: all ease 1s;
  -o-transition: all ease 1s;
  transition: all ease 1s;
}
.menu li:hover {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
.m1 {
  background: orange;
  z-index: 8;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu left m1">
  <div class="links l1">
    <ul>
      <li data-open=".m2">Architecture</li>
      <li data-open=".m3">Coding</li>
      <li data-open=".m4">Thesis</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The answers below are correct, I just want to stress out that margins/paddings are part of browser default styling - and there is more of it. Take a look at CSS resets - the most basic one on http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove space to the left and top, you must override default styling of your ul:

```
ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

and to center vertically, i'd do it like this:

```
.links ul{
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.links{
    height: 100%;   
}
```

Check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/caeth/nyob56wf/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Quick follow up question, how can I  make the width of the li equal to the text it has without messing the centering?

Comment: @JúlioCésarLuta you can do it with `display: table`, and then centering likewise the ul vertical centering, check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/caeth/nyob56wf/3/

Comment: Thanks again. What a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

By default the `<UL>` comes with padding which is why you are seeing the spacing on the left side of your links. If you set

```
.links ul {margin:0; padding:0;}
```

the extra space will be removed. As a suggestion I recommend setting all elements padding and margins to default to 0 to help deal with these types of issues.

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

For vertical aligned text if you have text that is all on the same line you cant set the `line-height` to be the same height as its container which will vertically align the text elements.